# Are there real axml editors or tools when working in Xamarin on MVVMCross projects?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I noticed it's almost impossible to edit axml using the GUI in Xamarin when working on MVVMCross projects.

Is axml known enough for an good editor to exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AXML` is in reality just `XML`. I think the ending is there only because of the editor Xamarin has, in order for it to know when to open. `AXML` content is exactly the same as Android `XML` layout files. But you are right, custom Views are not rendered in the Xamarin layout editor, which the one in Android Studio does.

I am not sure what the future plans for the Xamarin AXML editor are, but you could voice your concerns and suggestions on [UserVoice](http://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-suggestions/).